# What is the order of $GL(2,\Bbb C)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

So I know $GL(2,\Bbb C)$ is the group of invertible $2\times 2$ matrices.

> Are the only two elements in this group $$GL(2,\Bbb C)=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}\right\}?$$

So this would mean it has order $2$?

Comment: What about putting non-zero $a$ and $b$ on the diagonal and zeros elsewhere?

Comment: And is $C$ supposed to be $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Yes   C is suppose to be $C$

Comment: \$\mathbb C\$ produces $\mathbb C$

Comment: Also @Randall I don't know what u mean, there are infinite number of complex numbers so does this mean the group order is infinite?

Comment: Of course.  Won't any non-zero multiple of the identity matrix be in your group?

Answer (score 3):

Note that $$GL(2,\Bbb C):=\{A \in M_2(\Bbb C): \det A  \neq 0\}$$

Here, for instance, $\begin{pmatrix}1&a\\0&1 \end{pmatrix} \in GL(2,\Bbb C)$ for $a \in \Bbb C$. There are uncountable $a$'s in $\Bbb C$. So $|GL(2,\Bbb C)|$ is infinite.

---

Alternatively,if $G$ is finite, then order of any element divides order of $G$. But  note that, $$\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1 \end{pmatrix}^n=\begin{pmatrix}1&n\\0&1 \end{pmatrix}\neq I_2$$

That is, order of $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1 \end{pmatrix}$ is infinite. So..?